# Should I use WCF instead of DLL in c#

Tags: wcf, dll, architecture

I need some advice about using WCF or DLL in my program. I am developing a program that will be Desktop App and Web App. The architecture is multi tiers. What should I do in Bussiness layer, should I just make it as a namespace and build it to be a dll then in my Desktop App and Web App I add reference this dll OR should I make the business layer be a web service, then I can use in my apps. What I have to consider when using a web service instead of dll.

Comment: If you want the most flexibility, put the business logic into a class library (DLL).  Then, when/if you need a service, you can write one as a wrapper around the existing DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get started you could create one Solution that includes:

- Business logic project
- Web App project
- Desktop project

Web App project and Desktop project will just reference your Business logic project. Then(if needed) you could continue to separate Business logic project to e.g. Data Access project, Service Layer project etc.

Then if you will feel that you need "real" WCF service it would be easy to create one from your decoupled architecture.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this not what I asked. I understand the software structure well but my question is about what should I could consider when decide between dll and web service

Comment: I think it's all about who the consumers of this WCF/dll are. If you know in advance that there will be several consumers(that will desire to consume service via Network), then WCF could be a natural choice. If there are no(so far) consumers except yourself and you don't want difficulties with Network connections, firewalls etc, then DLL could be a natural choice. It is normal thing to start with simple(but decoupled) solution, and then evolve it to WCF if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use restful service like http webapi which has broad reach of clients